# How to print ダイスキ using Python 3.7 in Scite?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, windows-10, scite

I'm using Win10 & Scite with utf-8 enabled output window.
The file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM

Script:

```
print('ダイスキ from python 3')
```

The script can be run on `cmd prompt` without error. But when run on `Scite` it will produce error:

Output:

```
>pythonw.exe -u "test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print('\u30c0\u30a4\u30b9\u30ad from python 3')
  File "D:\BIN\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: character maps to <undefined>
>Exit code: 1
```

How to properly print ダイスキ to stdout using python3 with Scite?

---

***Updates:***

I've edited Scite Global Options file, to support utf-8.

```
code.page=65001
```

I've tested C, Lua, old Python 2.7, and it can print utf-8 strings (on Scite output window).

Seems to be Scite configuration error or a maybe Scite bug, because the Scite output terminal window works on Lua & C, but fail only on Python3.

[image: the script]

Comment: Why all the bending over backwards with `encode` and `decode`? What about a plain `print('ダイスキ')`?

Comment: Well, I think it's terminal output issue. The script can be run on `cmd prompt` but with strange text & no error. But if it run on `Scite`, it will produce error. It's definetely a `Scite` bug. It works on `C & Lua`, but fail with `Python3`.

Comment: What’s the error if you skip that `encode` `decode` dance?

Comment: It's same error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-requests.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("\u30c0\u30a4\u30b9\u30ad")
  File "D:\BIN\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: So simplify the question by skipping `encode` `decode`, because it likely has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is that UTF-8 output doesn’t work in your particular environment, let’s focus on that environment.

Comment: Edited your question, please ensure it’s still correct.

Comment: I added scite config to the question.

Comment: SciTE thinks the stdout encoding is `cp1252`.  Are you sure you are configuring SciTE correctly for UTF-8?

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I already changed to `code.page=65001` but still receive the same error message. I can print other unicode character except Japan/Chinese character.

Comment: The error message still says `encodings\cp1252.py`, so it thinks that's the stdout encoding.

Comment: According to https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html there is an `output.code.page` parameter as well.  Is that set and overriding `code.page`?

Comment: I set `output.code.page` but still return the same error. I just installed old Python 2.7 and it works fine with Scite & Unicode. Only Python 3.7 (C/J/K/Arabic character) doesn't work with Scite. It's very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scite involves popen() / piping the STDOUT.

Python 3.7 need env variable "PYTHONIOENCODING" to be set manually. So you need to add environment variable "PYTHONIOENCODING" set to "utf_8"

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Try to do this:

```
print(u'ダイスキ')
```